# Why doesn't my Java DSL Camel app work on JBoss Fuse?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Could you help me to figure out what's wrong with my application? It is in "Resolved" state as soon as I publish it to JBoss Fuse.

I've made a simple .csv parser using Apache Camel framework. I use .marshal()/unmarshal().csv() to parse the file.

I deploy it to OSGi and starts the JBoss Fuse server and this app in resolved state instead of active. 
But if I eliminate parsing then it works with ClassCastExceptions, but at least it is in active state. So it seems that OSGi can't resolve the marshalling but I've installed feature:camel-csv.

```
public final class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure(){
        from("file:/../?fileName=..")
                .unmarshal()
                .csv()
                .process(exchange ->
                        {
                            List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                            List<List<String>> newData = new ArrayList<>();
                            data.forEach(line -> {
                                List<String> newLine = chosenColumns
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(line::get)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                newData.add(newLine);
                            });
                            log.info(newData.toString());
                            exchange.getIn().setBody(newData);
                        }
                )
                .marshal()
                .csv()
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .to("file:/../?fileName=..");
    }
}
```

The code above represents the router.
Could you help me with it?

By the way the application is run via Activator and Maven contains following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.sample.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And in log:tail I see following:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat@6be36954] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file://C:/Users/Pavel_Polubentcev/Downlo... because of Data format 'csv' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3301)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3024)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819)
    at com.packt.camel.chapter3.Activator.start(Activator.java:18)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'csv' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.model.UnmarshalDefinition.createProcessor(UnmarshalDefinition.java:181)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
    ... 18 more
```

But camel-csv feature is installed and camel-csv is presented in pom.

Comment: There should be some message in the fuse log explaining why your bundle couldn't start. If you can't find that message then try reinstalling the bundle and then it should appear at the tail of the log

Comment: Hi, in what log? In hawtio, in "Log" tab nothing interesting and in JBoss Fuse Studio console some lines that CamelContext is started and after is shutting down automatically.

Comment: That would be the JBoss Fuse log - the one you get by running `log:tail` in the console.

Comment: Also, why are you using your own Activator? There's no need to use that when deploying bundles in Karaf. Unless it does something specific that you need then you should try to remove that and see if it works.

Comment: But it's the way to tell JBoss where my routes are located. What is another way to recognize them?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'csv' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath

Comment: Camel 2.12.4 is very old. You can try it with JBoss Fuse 6.3 or the latest Camel 2.21.2.